# Vertical alignment of floating divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to create a row, where three divs are positioned side by side:

[image: now]

In the divs, the middle one is always vertical aligned middle and the other ones are vertical aligned top.

I did this with the settings

```
Container:
display:table
Row:
display:table-row
Cell:
display:table-cell with float:none
```

This works fine, but now the requirement is, that only the last div should become vertical bottom aligned. (see attachment 2):

[image: goal]

Anyways, I couldn't manage it, since display table cell and vertical-align:top on the left and right div doesn't allow me to vertical align bottom.

I also tried to use position absolute on the last div, but I can't know if the variable height of the div is bigger in the left or in the right div

thanks for your help!

Comment: can we have some html+css code ?

Comment: Probably better to use flexbox here, than `display:table-*`.

Comment: If you really want to stay with tables you could `position:relative` the rightmost div and `position: absolute; bottom: 0px` the div that should be vertically aligned at the bottom.

Comment: Hey, yes, but what if the leftmost div is smaller than the rightmost div? then the position absolute, bottom 0 hack becomes to a workaround that does not work since the leftmost div controls the height of the whole row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`flexbox` can do that quite easily

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrap {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 5vh auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
}
.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
}
.left,
.right {
  flex: 2;
  /* just a number...means they are twice as wide as the middle */
}
.middle {
  justify-content: center;
}
header {
  flex: 0 0 25px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
nav {
  flex: 0 0 35px;
  background: blue;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.content {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background: orange;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
footer {
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  width: 50px;
  align-self: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="col left">
    <header></header>
    <nav></nav>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab, impedit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate cum magnam maiores unde consequuntur, similique deserunt delectus omnis expedita in, laborum praesentium consequatur
      eius adipisci saepe rerum reprehenderit nostrum temporibus.</div>
    <footer></footer>
  </div>
  <div class="col middle">
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col right">
    <header></header>
    <nav></nav>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus, modi!</div>
    <footer></footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does it, thank you very much: one more question: how do i make this responsive, so that the divs break if the have no place ? setting flex-wrap: warp did not help.

Comment: Ok, dump question, my solution is to set display:block; on the wrapper when a certain media query rule applies

Answer (score -2):

I would do this with flexbox: http://codepen.io/pjetr/pen/KpYzqj

```
div { display: flex; }
/* I was required to add some code, to accompany the codepen link :) */
```

but remember to check this: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes