# HTML5/CSS align list-items depending on other columns mutual height

Tags: jquery, css, html, vertical-alignment, flexbox

I got the following use case:

[image: Cols as Rows]

You can see three identical boxes: 
Each box beginns with a big rectangle box, that has a picture and variable content and thus has variable height.
the rest consists of a list, that is vertical aligned bottom, so that they should get the same height.

My goal is to "synchronize" the height of the < li >'s in each of these boxes. So it should not be important how many text you enter in such a < li > tag, the design should automatically handle the word-break and align the content like it was a row.

In other words, like Abhitalks stated, I want to align list-items to their peers in other content columns depending on the mutual heights.

Now, I used display flex in order to vertical align the list to bottom of the element.
You can find my used solution here: 
[Vertical alignment of floating divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31968330/vertical-alignment-of-floating-divs)

But now I got the problem, that if the list has no identical content (e.x. more than two rows per listitem, the whole thing shifts to the top.

However, is it somehow possible to simulate a row behavior with flexbox, but actually having a column structure?

I need a column structure, so I can easily get a responsive layout.

hope you understand my problem

thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/a1yr4u84/3/

You can see, that I made < br / >'s inside the li's content, in order to make the content fit.

```
<li>one <br /> two</li>
<li>one <br /> two <br /> three</li>
<li>one<br /><br /></li>
```

However, I can't control how many text there is going to be in the li's. And I don't want the user to hack with < br / >s but let the design handle the content, so I want the list inside the columns to behave like a row

Comment: You want to occupy full height of the parent container although the alignment is in row. Am I right? :)

Comment: No, I have full height in the parent container. I want to keep each row in the same height, although I use a column layout.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question through code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ...three identical boxes: first big rectangle part has
>   variable content and thus variable height. the rest consists of a
>   list, that is vertical aligned bottom, so that they should get the
>   same height.

You need nested `flex` here. Given this markup:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="col left">
    <img src="..." />
    <div class="content">
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col middle">
      <img src="" />
    <ul class="content">
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col right">
      <img src="..." />
    <ul class="content">
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

First `flex` the wrapper which will layout the columns in a row, and give a `flex-basis` of `33%` (approx) to the columns to allow for variable content in first columns to space out.:

```
.wrap { display: flex; }
.wrap .col { flex: 1 0 33%; }
```

Next, `flex` the columns to layout the image and content list in columns. This time `flex-basis` is not required:

```
.wrap .col { flex: 1 0 33%; display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
.col img, .col .content { flex: 0 0 auto; }
```

In order to keep the lists vertically aligned to the bottom, just provide a `margin-top:auto` to the list content:

```
.col .content { margin-top: auto; }
```

Here is a complete example..

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/a1yr4u84/1/**

**Snippet**:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.wrap {
  width: 80%; margin: 16px auto; padding: 12px; border: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
}
.wrap .col {
    flex: 1 0 33%; display: flex; flex-direction: column;
}
.col img, .col .content { flex: 0 0 auto; }
.col img { width: 128px; display: block; margin: 2px auto; }
.col .content { margin: auto 12px 0px 12px; }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="col left">
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/128/128" />
    <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab, impedit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col middle">
      <img src="//lorempixel.com/128/128" />
    <ul class="content">
        <li>one</li>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>one</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col right">
      <img src="//lorempixel.com/128/128" />
    <ul class="content">
        <li>one</li>
        <li>one</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Edit:

(*based on op's comment*)

If you want the list-items to align to their peers in other content columns depending on the mutual heights, then you cannot do this with CSS. I see that you have tagged the question with `jQuery`, so I am proposing a quick-and-dirty solution using jQuery.

Calculate the `height` of the list items, and apply that height to all the corresponding items in other columns:

**Fiddle 2: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/a1yr4u84/4/**

**Snippet 2**:

```js
var $lists = $('ul.content');

for (i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    var highest = 0;
    $lists.each(function(idx, elem) {
        var h = $(elem).children().eq(i).outerHeight();
        if (h > highest) highest = h;
    });
    $lists.each(function(idx, elem) {
        $(elem).children().eq(i).outerHeight(highest);
    });    
}
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.wrap {
  width: 80%; margin: 16px auto; padding: 12px; border: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
}
.wrap .col {
    flex: 1 0 33%; display: flex; flex-direction: column;
}
.col img, .col .content { flex: 0 0 auto; }
.col img { width: 128px; display: block; margin: 2px auto; }
.col .content { margin: 0px 12px 0px 12px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="col left">
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/128/128" />
    <ul class="content">
        <li>one <br /> two</li>
        <li>one <br /> two <br /> three</li>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>one</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col middle">
      <img src="//lorempixel.com/128/128" />
    <ul class="content">
        <li>one</li>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>one</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col right">
      <img src="//lorempixel.com/128/128" />
    <ul class="content">
        <li>one <br /> two</li>
        <li>one</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Note*: I have used an arbitrary number of `10` to loop thru the list-items. In production code, you must calculate the number of the list items in the largest list.

Comment: thanks, that gets near the solution, BUT: I need the lists beginn in the same row, although they are in the same column: see http://jsfiddle.net/a1yr4u84/2/ one two three spans three lines. I want that the middle and right column also start where one starts and the next item should be after three, independently how much content is inside.

Comment: @KyuuSung: That is not possible with css. You will have to use Javascript. I have updated the answer to include a possible solution. As it stands, your question and its title is highly ambiguous with respect to your problem. Please update the question cleaning it up and making it more clear.

Comment: Hey, I just tried your jquery code and got that last question; you said: "Note: I have used an arbitrary number of 10 to loop thru the list-items. In production code, you must calculate the number of the list items in the largest list.". What I don't get is, why you dont use idx (index of the each iteration) instead only iterating through in this example 10 items ?!

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, I didn't realize that the other .each iteration needs the current index to set the highest value.

Comment: @KyuuSung: Am sorry for the confusion. Actually `idx` is not being used at all. Only the `i` from the outer `for` loop. It is just out of my habit to include the `idx` and `elem` arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Set css `line-height` to the row objects. All need to be set of the same height.

Comment: `line-height` will  change as the content changes though, right?

Comment: It depends what content. If you use `image` with random `height` in the text, then no. If you use no image or only images with predefined heights, then it should be OK.