# Equal div's height, aligned highest div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

How to set green divs equals, aligned highest div? Divs contains text different lenghth. Red and blue divs always are same height. Orange divs are col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 and should be same height. I have got no idea.
[image]

Comment: Please post your current implemented code. We will improve it and find you a solution.

Comment: Something like this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/32587019/1355315. Ignore the edit on that answer. And also ignore the `margin` thingy in the first part of that answer. Rest is exactly the same as your use-case.

Comment: @Abhitalks If that is the case why not post a answer with the updated code instead of making a comment

Comment: @NooBskie: Because, I am not too sure if that is really what suits Op's purpose. If yes, then this question would be a dupe and should be marked as such. Else, we can then think of another solution provide Op presents their code in the question. Waiting for Op.

Answer (score 1):

**In Stackoverflow, you must send what have you did already when you have a problem.**

**Then we'll help you**.

> I implemented **[Responsive Equal Height Divs (codepen.io)](http://codepen.io/micahgodbolt/pen/FgqLc)** with your image.
>
> I found also that: [a responsive equal heights plugin for
>   jQuery](http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/)

```js
(function($) { 
  var equalheight = function(container) {

    var currentTallest = 0, currentRowStart = 0, rowDivs = new Array(), $el, topPosition = 0;
    $(container).each(function() {

     $el = $(this);
     $($el).height('auto')
     topPostion = $el.position().top;

     if (currentRowStart != topPostion) {
       for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
         rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
       }
       rowDivs.length = 0;
       currentRowStart = topPostion;
       currentTallest = $el.height();
       rowDivs.push($el);
     } else {
       rowDivs.push($el);
       currentTallest = (currentTallest < $el.height()) ? ($el.height()) : (currentTallest);
    }
     for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
       rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
     }
   });
  }
  $(window).load(function() {
    equalheight('.column-block .column-block-content');
  });
  $(window).resize(function(){
    equalheight('.column-block .column-block-content');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.column-block {
   width: 30% !important; // Hack just for good display in stackoverflow :D
}
.column-block-head {
  background: red; 
  height: 40px;
}

.column-block-content { 
  background: green; 
}

.column-block-foot {
  background: blue;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column-block col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div class="column-block-head">
    </div>
    <div class="column-block-content">
      Foobar<br>
    </div>
    <div class="column-block-foot">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column-block col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div class="column-block-head">
    </div>
    <div class="column-block-content">
      Foobar<br>
      Foobar<br>
    </div>
    <div class="column-block-foot">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column-block col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div class="column-block-head">
    </div>
    <div class="column-block-content">
      Foobar<br>
      Foobar<br>
      Foobar<br>
      Foobar<br>
      Foobar<br>
    </div>
    <div class="column-block-foot">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```